# Prevent Google from showing results from certain websites

Tags: google-search

Is there a way to *permanently* block sites from showing in Google search results?

By *permanently* I mean that I don't want to exclude websites manually in every search.

When I search for some web development questions, I like to see results from Stackoverflow and some other websites, but I hate to get results from OSDir and other websites that just duplicate SO content on their side (which btw I think is ridiculous).

Any idea?

Comment: Did you do any searching yourself to find an answer?

Comment: @DaveRook He did, but those sites were blocked from being in the results..

Comment: @DaveRook No. I don't know how to use a search engine. Hence my question. Do you think I should delete my question?

Comment: @DaveRook I am really sorry that you are having such a bad day. I hope tomorrow will be a better day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a plugin

This is for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef?hl=en

And for FireFox https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go/ (thank you to @Nikolay for posting it in the comments of this post)

> Blocks domains/hosts from appearing in your Google search results

Comment: And [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-unwanted-results-of-go/) is plugin for Firefox

Comment: I somehow only see your answer now... but thanks for that! I'll give a try to the Chrome plugin as I usually use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You could also build a [Google Custom Search Engine](https://www.google.com/cse), which allows you to limit your search to certain sites, prioritize select sites over other sites, &/or exclude certain sites from your search results.